# I am having a problem setting state with returned json data

Tags: reactjs, json

I am doing a project messing around with The Movie Data Base Api. I am using fetch to grab saved id's (I am storing them in a fake rest api, JSON SERVER) and then looping through them and for each id I am making a fetch to retrieve the particular movie the id is associated with. I am using Promise.All to achieve this. After Pushing the data into an empty array I am able to get back what I need in a console.log() if I log the array, but the minute I try to use useState() and pass the array in it starts infinitely making requests. Maybe Someone can point me in the right direction? Thank you

```js
    let moviesToReturn = []
    
    const [favorites, setFavorites] = useState([])

    let requests = movieId.map(id => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            request({
                url: `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${id.movieId}?api_key=${movieApikey}`,
                method: 'GET'
            },
                (err, res, body) => {
                    if (err) { reject(err) }                           //function passed to the promise
                    resolve(body)
                })
        })
    })

    Promise.all(requests).then((body) => {
        body.forEach(res => {
            if (res)
                moviesToReturn.push(JSON.parse(res))
                console.log(moviesToReturn, 'movies to return')
               return setFavorites(moviesToReturn)
        })
    }).catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the api at the initial rendering and then set the state. Therefore, you need to use `useEffect` having empty dependency array as follows. The way you have done it will cause the application to render it infinitely.

Additionally, `setState` function doesn't return anything.

```
useEffect(() => {
  let requests = movieId.map((id) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      request(
        {
          url: `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${id.movieId}?api_key=${movieApikey}`,
          method: "GET",
        },
        (err, res, body) => {
          if (err) {
            reject(err);
          } //function passed to the promise
          resolve(body);
        }
      );
    });
  });

  Promise.all(requests)
    .then((body) => {
      let moviesToReturn = []; /* keep moviesToReturn array here */

      body.forEach((res) => {
        if (res) moviesToReturn.push(JSON.parse(res));
        console.log(moviesToReturn, "movies to return");
      });

      setFavorites(moviesToReturn);
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
}, []);
```